# Zener Diode three terminal application

Tags: components, diodes, zener

I am looking for a three terminal zener diode that can handle at least 125V (DC).  Please post links to where I can check out a spec sheet of this component, if it exists.

Comment: A zener diode has two terminals. What you're referring to will probably be a (zener based) shunt regulator IC.

Comment: yes sir that is what i am looking for i need it to rectify at a higher voltage then the ones ive seen so far.  Highest ive seen was around 37V

Answer (score 3):

125V is rather a lot for a diode.  But digikey sells two-terminal zeners up to 200V.

If you really need the precision of a three-terminal part, consider this arrangement:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, a cascoded transistor to extend the voltage range. I'd use resistors with about 10x the values, though, just to keep their power dissipation down. How about 40k2, 9k76 and 1k02, all standard 1% values?

Comment: @DaveTweed Good point. You could go 100x and not affect accuracy much.  TL431 is 4uA max input current on the reference pin.